# cannot send post request in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send a post request and it give me this error. I think the error is caused by something in the controller but I do not know what it is. I've provided all the related codes. Can anyone help me to fix the error ?

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'first_name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`first_name`,
>   `last_name`, `email`, `phone_number`, `password`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (?,      ?, ?, ?, ?, 2020-02-26 07:54:56, 2020-02-26
>   07:54:56))

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $user = new User();

        $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
        $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
        $user->password = $request->password;

        $user->save();

        return new UserResource($user);
    }
```

Model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

UserResource:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        // return parent::toArray($request);

        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'last_name' => $this->last_name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'phone_number' => $this->phone_number,
            'password' => $this->password
        ];
    }
}
```

migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone_number');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Request body:

```
{
    'first_name': 'ayman',
    'last_name': 'tarig',
    'email': 'ayman@email.com',
    'phone_number': '010010100',
    'password': '1234'
}
```

Comment: check the error  first_name value is  not null in DB,  and  $request->first_name is empty then error is created

Comment: Your $request->first_name must be blank. check that

Comment: @Sehdev Yes it's blank but why? I assign a value on the request body

Comment: how are you sending the post request? Also share the output of `dd($request->all());`

Comment: share your HTML plz

Comment: @Sehdev I'm using postman to test the request. The output of ```dd($request->all())``` is empty. This is the cause of the error but I don't know why It's empty

Comment: the `first_name` is null as it stated. Definitely, double check how you send the params in your postman.

Comment: @Ιησούςτουναυή yes I send all the params in postman. I've shared the post request body in the question

Comment: can you show us the *request* inside your controller. try`dd(request()->all())` pls.

Comment: @Ιησούςτουναυή it giving an empty array

Comment: that means you failed to send the params. You should double check your postman. I think this will help you on how https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5n07Ybz7yI

Comment: It seems you are sending your request as `raw` in postman. Have you changed request from `text` to `Json(application/json)` in postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you may use **[Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)** from the Eloquent ORM,

**From the Laravel Eloquent ORM Documentation**

> You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the method. However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

In order to make your field updated you need to use the `fillable` array of an Eloquent model:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $fillable = [
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'phone_number',
            'password',
     ];
}
```

You way want to use a custom request in order to verify in provided data is in correct format and not null: **[laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation)**

> For more complex validation scenarios, you may wish to create a "form request". Form requests are custom request classes that contain validation logic.

As follows:

```php
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone_number' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Mass assignment only happens where you use User::create(['first_name' => $request->first_name]); This is not the case

Comment: Also, the user has added `public $guarded = [];`

Comment: @lizeshakya yes, I just think is a better solution using Mass Assignment in 
combination with a Form Request class in order to have 
minimum possible of complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've followed the exact setups that you've take and the error isn't solved yet. the output of ```dd($request->all())``` is empty for some reason that I don't know and that what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

if you making this request through a html form, make sure that the name of each input you spelled correctly. And if you using postman then make sure that you have sent a post request, because all thing are looking good.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import Illuminate\Http\Request

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Then using postman try to invoke your post method.